# Differentiable curve geometry

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives

Let f (x, y) = x² + y² and let λ (t) = (x (t), y (t)) be a differentiable curve whose image is contained in the level curve f (x, y) = 1, that is, for all t in the domain of λ, f (x (t), y (t)) = 1 (give an example of such a curve). Let λ (t₀) = (x₀, y₀). Prove that λ '(t₀), ∇f (x₀, y₀) = 0. Interpret geometrically.

Suggestion: for all t in the domain of λ, (x (t))²+ (y (t))² = 1; derive from t and make t = t₀)

Someone? I really need some help with this

Answer (score 0):

Let us derive $x(t)^2 + y(t)^2=1$; we have $x(t) x'(t)+ y(t) y'(t)=0$, that is $\lambda(t).\lambda'(t)=0$ (scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^2$). $\lambda(t)$ describes the position of a moving object in a circle; $\lambda'(t)= (x'(t), y'(t))$ is its speed. The speed is tangent to the circle and speed and position are perpendicular.

Comment: You haven't mentioned $\nabla f$.